# Node.js can not use crypto as a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

```
const { hashGen } = require('crypto');

var hash = hashGen('sha256').update(hash).digest('hex');
```

I am being given the error:
TypeError: hashGen is not a function

I tried to create a password with a salt in front of it, and then hash it with SHA-256, but I am just getting the error upon running.

Comment: Where on https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html do you see `hashGen`?

Comment: It's called `createHash` and not `hashGen`. Check the docs as jonrsharpe said.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are writing the function wrong

you can create with:

```
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256', secret)
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-crypto-createhash-method/

and if you want to make a password hash, try Bcrypt, sha256 is safe but is a fast hash, is not impossivble to discover, exist databases to this (with inumerous hashs and your content)